# bootstrap でnavbar が正しく表示されません

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

html の勉強を始めたばかりなのですが、container や　jumbotronなどは使えるのにnavbarが正しく表示されません。
bootstrapのNAVSやNAVBARから直接コピペしても表示がホームページにある例とは異なる形で表示されてしまうので何が間違っているのかが全く分からない状態で困っています。
udemyを主な学習材料に使っていましたが、教材にはこのような場合の留意点などはありませんでした。困り果てて別の教材も買ってみたのですが同様でした。
htmlのコード以外などでbootstrap使用時に注意しなければならないことなどがあれば教えていただきたいです。

よろしくお願いします。

写真では[Tabsのコード](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#nav-tabs)をそのままコピーしています。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2):

スクリーンショットを見る限り、bootstrapの前にhtmlについて勉強する必要があります。特に`<html>`タグや`<body>`タグの役割といった基礎の基礎の知識が足りてないように見受けられます。

とりあえずの解決策としては、全てのコンテンツは`</body>`の手前に書く必要があります。